# Printing a function as String in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, quine

Dart question about printing function as a string -

I have this code on Dart-

```
sum(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
```

If i run  -

```
print(sum.toString());
```

I get -

```
Closure: () => dynamic from Function 'sum':.
```

If i run it on JavaScript -

```
console.log(sum.toString());
```

the print is -

```
// "sum(a, b) {
// return a + b;
// }"
```

How do i do the same print like I show in JavaScript but in Dart?

Thanks friends!

Comment: Not possible in Dart unless you are using some kind of builder which can save this information. What do you need this for?

Comment: I need to make an app that shows functions string on a page and run run those functions also.

Comment: And I'll ask "why do you need that?  you can't turn that string back into a function at runtime..."